# Oracle 12C compatability with Sonar 5.0.1

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Our DB team is upgrade Oracle to 12C. We currently have Sonar 5.0.1. Is Sonar 5.0.1 compatible with Oracle 12C

Comment: hello,can anyone help me

Comment: SonarSource Team ..please respond